# where is the derived class in public virtual void?

Tags: c#, .net

I'm new to c# and don't understand someone else's code.  There is a class called SolutionStep.  It contains a method called

```
public static void Calc (SolutionData SD, RunData RD)
```

Within that, there is a call to

```
WorkEntryPoint.CalcDervs(RD)
```

Within CalcDervs there are these two lines

```
WorkBlock DervsBlock = WorkBlock.Get(RD);
DervsBlock.Calc()
```

Within the WorkBlock class, Calc is defined:

```
public void Calc()
{
    foreach (Work_Base Work in Works)
    {
        Work.Calc(RunDataBlock);
    }
}
```

The class Work_Base looks like this:

```
public class Work_Base
{ 
    public Work_Base()
    {
        WorkStack.Add(this);
    }

    public virtual void Calc(RunData RD)
    {
    }
}
```

I've read that virtual means that the derived class will override it but I don't see where that is happening.  Can anyone shed some light?

Thanks for responses.  Its difficult to understand.  I don't see any class being derived with the colon ":", nor do I see any "override" in any of the declarations.

Comment: What is the relation between `WorkBlock` and `Work_Base`?

Comment: You need to find the class (or classes) that inherits `Work_Base`.  Something like `class AnotherWork : Work_Base`

Comment: @zerkms: It seems clear that WorkBlock contains a collection of Work_Base, named `Works`

Comment: `virtual` means it *can* be overridden, not that it necessarily has. But in order for it to be overridden it would need the `override` keyword, and to have the same signature as the base class.

Comment: @Ben Voigt: I prefer not to guess until the `WorkBlock` class declaration is provided.

Comment: Well i didn't see any code of yours overriding it, if you want a different implementation from the base then you must override the method. And make sure the class is inheriting from your base class.

Try typing "override(space)" and intellisense should provide you with overridable methods

Comment: Work_Base can be many different types and while many people here scratch the surface of your question. what you really want is to search your library for classes that inherit from Work_base. jmcilhinney has the best answer. but you need to find the code that adds objects to `Works` to find the types that are implementing Calc

Answer (score 3):

It's not happening anywhere in the code you provided.  This part:

```
foreach (Work_Base Work in Works)
```

means that `Works` is a list that contains objects where each one either is type `Work_Base` or is a type that inherits `Work_Base`.  There's no indication in that code which each one is.  You can determine the type of each item in a variety of ways, e.g.

```
Console.WriteLine(Work.GetType())
```

That will tell you the actual type of the current item.  Once you know that type, you can look for the implementation of that type specifically.

As has been said, any types derived from `Work_Base` **can** override `Calc` but they don't **have to**.  If they don't then calling their `Calc` method will simply invoke the base implementation, which does nothing.  If the author of `Work_Base` wanted to require that every derived class implement their own `Calc` method then they would have to declare it `abstract` and not implement it in the base class.

Answer (score 0):

First of all,virtual means that every derived class is entitled to use keyword 'override' to rewrite your method.

However you are not forced to rewrite it.

But you should be aware that these only happen in the derived classes,not you current base class.

And you need to learn c# inherent mechanism and difference btw keyword 'new' and 'override'.

Answer (score 0):

> virtual means that the derived class will override

`virtual` means that derived class *can* override it, i.e. parent class allows to do it, "legally".

```
class WorkBase
{
    public virtual void Calc() {}
}

class WorkA : WorkBase
{
    public override void Calc() {}
}

WorkBase a = new WorkA();
a.Calc(); // overridden method is called
```

But if:

```
class WorkBase
{
    public void Calc() {} // no keyword 'virtual'
}

class WorkB : WorkBase
{
    public new void Calc() {} // note keyword 'new'
}
```

Then:

```
WorkB b = new WorkB();
b.Calc(); // new method is called

WorkBase w = new WorkB();
w.Calc(); // base method id called
```